# fsnotify go library not working watch changes in FTP server

Tags: go

I have some cases to watch file changes, it work properly in local system, but not working when i try in FTP server:

```golang
func main() {
    // connect FTP
    conn, err := ftp.Dial(config.FTP_ADDR)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    err = conn.Login(config.FTP_USERNAME, config.FTP_PASSWORD)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    // change dir
    err = conn.ChangeDir("./public_html/csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    fileCsvPath := "thisfile.csv"

    // creates a new file watcher
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR", err)
    }
    defer watcher.Close()

    //
    done := make(chan bool)

    //
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            // watch for events
            case event := <-watcher.Events:
                printEvent(event)

                // watch for errors
            case err := <-watcher.Errors:
                fmt.Println("ERROR", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    // out of the box fsnotify can watch a single file, or a single directory
    if err := watcher.Add(fileCsvPath); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR:", err)
    }

    <-done
}
```

This code:

```golang
watcher.Add(fileCsvPath)
```

contain the path, but when i change to path in FTP server it's print:
**ERROR: GetFileAttributes: The system cannot find the file specified.**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`fsnotify` utilizes operating system ability to see events from **local** filesystem driver when files on that filesystem are modified. It will not work with most networked filesystems as files are modified on server and not on local filesystem so local OS cannot see modification events.

When a file is changed on FTP server, OS where FTP server is running might see that event but there's no such feature in FTP protocol to communicate event down to FTP client on your computer (same for NFS, Samba and other networked filesystems). `fsnotify` will only work on local filesystems (and not all of them).

`fsnotify` FAQ relevant to this question:

> Why don't notifications work with NFS filesystems or filesystem in userspace (FUSE)?
>
> fsnotify requires support from underlying OS to work. The current NFS protocol does not provide network level support for file notifications.

Comment: Is there a way to watch file changes in ftp server?

Comment: To my knowledge the only option is polling and checking if file has changed continuously. Depending on FTP server software you might be lucky and server might support e.g. `HASH` (or `XMD5` or `XCRC`) command that will give you file hash (so you don't have to download file to check if it changed since the last poll - other would be checking date of last modification with `UTIME` but that might not be reliable).